# how to count the number of paths I can take given a coordinates (x,y) using one step/two steps down or left to get to (0.0)? in C

Tags: c, recursion

I need help writing a **recursive** code for my question (the recursion ends when both of them x and y are zero),for exapmle the input (2,1)to get to (0,0), the expected output should be 5 :[enter image description here][1]

this is what I have written so far but its not correct ..its maybe correct for one step down /left but not also two steps :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int numOfPaths(int x,int y);
int main()
{
    int x=0,y=0,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the initial coordinates of Alice and her friends:");
    if(scanf("%d%d", &x, &y)!=2)
    {
        printf("invalid input/n");
        return 0;
    }
   
    sum=numOfPaths(x,y);
    printf("The number of paths Alice and her friends have is:%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
/*the change that I made on the function */
int numOfPaths(int x, int y)
{
    if(x==0 && y==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return(numOfPaths(x-1,y) + numOfPaths(x,y-1) +numOfPaths(x,y-2) + numOfPaths(x-2,y));
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDxBF.png
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem more? Can `x` and `y` decrease simultaneously? Does the recursion end when one or both are zero?

Comment: NO , not simultaneously  ,one at a time and yes I think its clear in the question that I want it to end at (0,0)-both of them.

Comment: The problem description "*its not correct*" is not sufficient. Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the actual output you get and the expected output. If it's not obvious, explain why the actual output is wrong and why the expected output is correct. I suggest to show a simple example and explain which paths are possible.

Comment: @sallyazzam Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. If someone asks, then your impression that *it's clear in the question* might not be correct. I suggest to make the question even more clear.

Comment: I just edite it ...hope that can help @Bodo

Comment: Assume a 2x2 square, you starting at 1,1 going down to 0,0 – you can go either via 0,1 or via 1,0 in first step, and from there on on both branches is only one single path left. You get two paths in total. *Your* function would return 3. Why are you adding 1 to the sum of the two sub-paths?

Comment: @sallyazzam You did not mention the actual output. When I enter `2 1`, the result is `5`. (I don't know if this is just coincidence or if your algorithm is correct.) As you wrote that 5  is the expected result, this case does not show a problem. You should provide an example that shows a wrong result. According to the title and the image you can move one or two steps in the same direction. I don't see this in your code. I think the condition `if(x<1 || y<1)` is wrong. In this case you can go only in one direction but depending on the position you can choose different steps (1 or 2).

Comment: Side note: `return` is not a function, please don't add parentheses around the return value (luckily your in C, in C++ there's even a situation where you could produce invalid results that way...).

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah I see that now , although that doesn't make my code a correct answer for my question , can u help ??

Comment: Could you explain why you would expect 5 paths on 2,1? In your image 1st and 2nd as well as 3rd and 4th path are duplicates of each other.

Comment: @Bodo u can ignore my code because its not correct at all , is there any advice u can give me or maybe help me with a new code ??

Comment: My understanding: There's *exactly* one decision leading to 2,0, and from there on there are no further decisions possible. From 2,1 there's only yet another decision left, leading to 1,1 – and that one can, as my first comment showed, provide yet two further paths (where one of meets the very first path). Three paths in total.

Comment: @Aconcagua no its no the same , u can see in the image that sometime u can move one step and then another step ** or ** two steps at once .

Comment: @sallyazzam If your code is wrong, we should probably go back a step and discuss the algorithm. Do you think that you know an algorithm and the implementation in your code is wrong? Or do you think your algorithm is wrong? We can also help you to find problems in your algorithm (if it's not too complicated). In this case you should describe your algorithm.

Comment: @sallyazzam Wait, you didn't mention anywhere that steps further than to next visiting node are possible... How far can you jump at most? Right the entire way from start value down to 0?

Comment: @Bodo I prefer if u really ignore my code and helped mw with a new algorithm /code because I thought of the solution a lot but didn't came up with anything useful .

Comment: In any case you need to reflect all of these possible jumps! In maximum case this could mean iterating over all available jumps: `unsigned int sum = 0; if(x) { for(xx = x; xx--;) { sum += num(xx, y); } if(y) { while(y--) { sum += num(x, y); } }`

Comment: Yet another problem is your stop condition: Just returning 1 is not correct either, you have more than one path available, for instance if x is 0 but y is 2 then you can go to 0,0 directly and via 0,1, thus 2 paths, so you need to return `y` if `x` is 0 and `x` if `y` is 0 (still assuming maximum jumps allowed)...

Comment: Side note: I'm pretty sure that there exists a closed formula – for both, just jumping to neighbouring node allowed as well as when maximum steps are allowed (or any number in between).

Comment: If x or y is less than 0, the number of paths is zero, because there is no way to get to (0, 0) from (x, y) with steps to the left or down. If x and y are both zero, the number of paths is one, because the only solution is the “empty path,” that is, zero steps. Otherwise, you can get to (x, y) in one step from any of (x-2, y), (x-1, y), (x, y-2), or (x, y-1), so the number of paths to get to (x, y) equals the sum of the numbers of paths to each of those points.

Comment: @sallyazzam: My comment says “If x or y is less than 0, the number of paths is zero,” but that is not reflected in your code as shown in the question now. And **never** describe a problem merely as “it didnt work.” Always state any inputs needed to reproduce the problem, what the observed behavior is, what the desired behavior is, and, if not obvious, the difference between the observed behavior and the desired behavior. For example, “With input of 5 for x and 3 for y, the program prints 299, but the expected result is 34.” Or “The program executes and apparently does not stop.”

Comment: Side note: Is negative input legal at all? If not then you really should prefer `unsigned int` as input, and as apparently number of paths *cannot* get negative either, an unsigned return value would be better choice as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet I can have with the description of your problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numOfPaths(int x, int y)
{   
    // If you're arrived
    if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // If you're out of bound
    if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Trying the 4 possibility
    return numOfPaths(x - 1, y) + numOfPaths(x, y - 1) + numOfPaths(x - 2, y) + numOfPaths(x, y - 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("The number of paths Alice and her friends have is : %d", numOfPaths(2, 1));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank u so much ...since I asked the question here I solved it just like u but I didn't take into consideration /*the out of bound*/ which seems silly because its important and can not be forgotten .